# Address in use on TCP socket bind

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, bind

### Edit: I'd forgotten to close one set of the accepted sockets. Once I got them all, the problem went away. This surprises me because close() happens implicitly when the process exits and I didn't think the implicit and explicit close happened differently, but somehow the combination of explicit shutdown for write and subsequent explicit close did the trick. There's a mystery to be solved here but I'm not going to solve it; I have my restart working. I'll leave the original question here for the curious:

I realize the question has already been asked, but I need a more precise answer. The answer might be "you can't" but I need that spelled out clearly.

I have an application (running on wheezy on a raspberry pi) which acts as a server, accepting TCP socket connections. As such it starts out doing `socket()/setsockopt(listener_, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR...)/bind()/listen()`. Shortly thereafter there's a loop doing `accept()`s. All very standard. Generally this works fine.

But at intervals I update the server executable, and it's written to detect this, shut itself down, and let a script restart the new version. As it shuts down it does a close() on the listener socket. It also does a shutdown for write on all associated sockets it got from accept.

Invariably when it restarts it runs into the bind failure. The script tries to restart it over and over, with 5 second delays, but it stays in that state, failing over and over.

For various reasons it's very important that the server restart immediately. It's controlling hardware and long down times aren't acceptable. I can solve it by rebooting the pi, but that takes too long to come up for this to be a viable solution.

Because having the server exit is an event I can control, it seems to me that there ought to be something I can do on the server side before I `exit()`, to mitigate this. But what?

I can think of hack workarounds. I can try binding to each of a range of ports in turn, and then teach all the (many, varied) clients to try the same range of ports at connect time. That's painful. Is it really the only option?

Comment: Not a solution, but you should certainly *close* all the accepted sockets, not just shut them down. The restart should succeed when all the TIME_WAIT states have cleared, which should only take two minutes. I guess you could consider *resetting* all the accepted sockets, which means there are no TIME_WAIT states at all, but it might upset the clients, as pending outbound data is lost.

Comment: Correction. SO_REUSEADDR should overcome any TIME_WAIT states. It must be the failure to close the accepted sockets.

Comment: Thanks. Edited my post.

Comment: Whether `close()` happens for open sockets when the process exits, or whether they are reset, or nothing, as apparently happened here, depends on the platform. There was never any reason to think that shutdown would be sufficient. You don't need both 'close for write' and close. `close()` is sufficient.